# importing maven project to STS IDE

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to import my maven project to STS IDE but whenever it's close to completion, an error message saying "could not save project location" pops up. I don't know what to do.

first, I thought I maybe created a Gradle project instead of maven but when I downloaded a maven project i faced the same issue. I've been watching tutorials online but can't seem to get a solution.
I was expecting to have my project appear in the project explorer site.